# Frankfurt Text-to-Speech service gives Unauthorized when Dallas TTS doesn't

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I have a nodeJS web app that I have deployed many times to Frankfurt and suddenly the `TextToSpeechV1.synthesize` call is returning the message.

```
 "Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." with stack info: "Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
at Request._callback (/Users/troy/git/WA-for-Auto-WebApp-master/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/lib/requestwrapper.js:102:21)
at Request.self.callback (/Users/troy/git/WA-for-Auto-WebApp-master/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/troy/git/WA-for-Auto-WebApp-master/node_modules/request/request.js:1157:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:185:15)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/troy/git/WA-for-Auto-WebApp-master/node_modules/request/request.js:1079:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)"
```

This doesn't happen if I switch the `username`, `password` and `url` to a TTS running for the same web app in Dallas region.  This was working earlier.  The `username`, `password` and `url` are from a TTS service in Frankfurt so I know those are right and valid.

I've tried creating a brand new TTS service in Frankfurt and use the iam_apikey but there I just get null back from the synthesize call and null back on the object returned in the callback.

I'm using `watson-developer-cloud` 3.13.0, but I was using 3.5.0 without problems.  Both 3.13.0 and 3.5 have behaved the same.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and I'll do better next time.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to the standard plan fixed the problem.  The TTS service in Dallas was standard plan, but the TTS service in Frankfurt was lite plan.  Something must have changed in the lite plan that caused this to break as it was working earlier.